# objective c - pass array of objects to table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i need to pass array of class objects 
i have class called Student , it has some properties (name , code , account_type ....);

i call method in database to get all students object

```
Student_array = [data_base_helper selectAllStudents];
```

i need to show list of student names in table view, i made anther array called names

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [Student_array count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cell_identifer = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cell_identifer forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cell_identifer];
    }



 for(Student * st in student_array){
        [self.names  addObject:st.student_name];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];

    return cell;
}
```

i find some problem with delete as i delete by index idea how to pass array of objects in table view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you don't need to use an "array of names", you can just use your Students array directly, in this way:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [Student_array count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cell_identifer = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cell_identifer forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cell_identifer];
    }

    Student *student = Student_array[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = student.student_name;

    return cell;
}
```

When you'll need to delete a student from the tableView, you can easily remove from the array and then update the tableView accordingly, something like that:

```
[Student_array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Note that in the code above I'm assuming that you want to delete the object at the given `indexPath.row` and that Student_array is a `NSMutableArray` and not a `NSArray`

ps: you may want to rename `Student_array` in `students` since in objective-c it's not a good practice to name objects with a capital letter, nor to use underscores. Likely I would also rename `student_name` in `name` since student is just a repetition of the type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

When You Deleted a cell from table delete items for both array Student_array and self.name array corresponding the deleted cell.